# .htaccess not working on XAMPP mac

Tags: macos, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

When trying to add my .htaccess file on XAMPP for Mac OSX it throws a Error 500.

I already tried to edit all apache config files to "AllowOverride All", however it still throws me a error 500 what ever I do.

Here is my .htaccess:

```
//Prevent viewing of .htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

//Prevent directory listings
Options All -Indexes

//RewriteEngine
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /b2b/index.php?page=$1&pg=$2&cat=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /b2b/index.php?page=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've searched everywhere but can't seem to find a working soulution.

Comment: where did you put this file in your structure?

Comment: Root of the given website/project. Which would be like this: Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/b2b/

Comment: If you suddenly get an http status 500 that means that file _is_ evaluated, but contains an error, so crashes. Check your http servers error log file, that is where the specific error appears.

Comment: so nobody may enter your site?

Comment: it doesn't work even if I only have the rewrite rule or the denying of viewing .htaccess file only in the file. throws a 500 no matter what is in that document

Answer (score -2):

All fixed by using AMPPS instead of XAMPP.